# Need to configure more than three redis server for session Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, redis

I have three radis server with load balancing. the radis session is shared by global for all instance. i configure the radis cache for magento2 EE session in env.php for single radis url. I need to configure the three radis URL in env.php. because if any one radis server down it need to switch to other server.

How i can configure the multiple radis session in single website.